What words used throughout the world have a similar sound to "capture" and does the word have a similar meaning?
I was reading with reference to alcázar and I was wondering and searching for a word in English that sounds like al cázar or al capture or al caesar.
Note that al-caesar means something like "to the king" or "to the emperor."
My question is, what different words have been used in Europe over the last few centuries for capture? Perhaps I can find an English cognate for one of them.

"alcázar" came into Spanish, via Aramaic and Arabic, from the Latin word castrum meaning "castle", so there are plenty of English cognates: castle, chateau, castrate, Chester, Castro...  But they're not related to capture.

Below are some good candidates, but this list is not comprehensive.
I hope that someone else's answer receives more upvotes than mine.
capiō
capta
captae
captam
capte
captibus
captor
captum
captured
captus
captuum
captuī
captā
captārum
captās
captī
captīs
captīvus
captō
captōrum
captōs
captū
captūra
captūs
captus
carl
cember
cense
censum
ces
chette
cial
ciation
ciple
culine
culis
kaptós
king
kurdî
käpt̪us
käpt̪ʊs̠

